# how to check which sheet is empty in excel workbook in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, oledb

I am accessing excel workbook in c# application. I am showing the sheet names to user by using list `lstSheetsEx`. But I want to exclude the empty sheet before showing to user.

```
        using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionStringExcel))
        {
            connExcel.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            List<string> lstSheetsEx = dtSchema.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME").Trim(new char[] { '\'', '$' })).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to show the sheet name exclude the empty sheet.

Code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = Checknullsheet("D:\\3.XLSX");
            list.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static List<string> Checknullsheet(string FileName)
        {

            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            int totalSheet = 0; //No of sheets on excel file  
            using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"))
            {
                objConn.Open();
                DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string sheetName = string.Empty;
                List<string> sheetlist = new List<string>();
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    var tempDataTable = (from dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                         where !dataRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase")
                                         select dataRow).CopyToDataTable();
                    dt = tempDataTable;
                    totalSheet = dt.Rows.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalSheet; i++)
                    {
                        table = makeDataTableFromSheetName(FileName, dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                        table.TableName = dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        set.Tables.Add(table);
                        sheetlist.Add(dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                    }
                    sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                }

                foreach (DataTable item in set.Tables)
                {
                    if(item.Rows.Count<=0)
                    {
                        sheetlist.Remove(item.TableName);
                    }
                }
                objConn.Close();
                return sheetlist; //Returning Dattable  
            }
        }
        private static DataTable makeDataTableFromSheetName(string filename, string sheetName)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection myConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
            "data source='" + filename + "';" +
            "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\" ");

            DataTable dtImport = new DataTable();
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter myImportCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", myConnection);
            myImportCommand.Fill(dtImport);
            return dtImport;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it with `OleDb`?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan, I have updated my code as you mentioned. Please check it.

Comment: can the empty sheet names be removed from datatable `table` rather than list `sheetlist`?

Comment: What is the function of **FilterDatabase** ?

Comment: why are you use `tempdataTable`. What is the need of this?

Comment: In `Checknullsheet` method `sheetName` is used for?